# System doesn't show option to select operating system during startup!

Tags: grub2

i am new at linux and ubuntu,
today i installed ubuntu 12.04 but during installation some problem happened, i don't remember what was that exactly (but can tell you that it was related to boot), so i reinstalled ubuntu (using usb stick both time) and ubuntu installation finished successfully,

Now problem is that when I start my computer then system is directly selecting ubuntu as my operating system, i have installed it along with windows 7 in option during installation, so it should give me option to select which operating system i want to use. I don't know what may be the problem.

Also, I want to know where ubuntu is installed (which directory)?
i just selected default setting during installation as i am noob in these things.

/**
i think i found problem, problem is that during startup the selection of operating system is hidden behind this square box saying that 'out of range 92.5khz / 58hz' , i was able to guess windows 7 option will be last so using my sense i can choose operating system now. but now again new problem that message (i think there is some screen resolution problem so desktop is unable to display window saying that out of range),

i have no idea how to solve this problem now.)
*/

---- solution--------

GRUB. I download GRUB Customizer and change the resolution of the screen and now I can see all the menu!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! When you installed Ubuntu, did you boot your machine from the LiveUSB, or did you install it in Windows using Wubi?

Comment: i installed it using live usb

Comment: Could you run the [BootInfoScript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net) and paste it's output here? It'd be useful for future visitors to help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

As someone explained, Sudo Update-grub should have done it for you , If not , You must restart ,Then at the beginning of boot before Ubuntu even dares to try to show up , Click Shift

Click Shift , Click Multiple or Hold , Then it says Loading Grub
Then you have your options , Click the recovery mode , And you can update grub from one of the options there , That is like a Back-up if the Terminal Commands fail you.

If that doesn't work , Then you might need to re-install Windows , I am having trouble with that myself so I can't help you there.

Comment: it shows windows 7 in terminal during use of sudo udate-grub, and you mean i am having to hold shift+multiply symbol key during startup to get recovery mode?

Comment: @samsher To force the GRUB2 menu to show at boot, you should only need to hold down the Shift key while the machine is starting. From there you should be able to select recovery mode from the menu.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply in time but warrior understood what I meant , I meant It might need multiple presses or Holding the key , I hope you solve your problem

Comment: problem solved, i've answered in the question about problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install grub customizer and change the boot splash wait time http://webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: it says sudo: grub: command not found @srinivas

Comment: yes it worked now, what it will do btw?

Comment: restart your comp

Comment: nothing happed same problem, ubuntu stared without asking for chose operating system

Comment: install grub customizer and change the boot splash wait time http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html

Comment: @SrinivasGowda The OP indicated in their post that this comment resolved their problem. Can you post it as a separate answer so they can accept it and properly mark the problem as solved? Thanks!

Comment: yes you are right @WarriorIng64, btw whene i click on ^ sign popup says Please login or register to vote for this post (click on this box to dismiss). but i already logged in?

Comment: @WarriorIng64  posted my comment as a new answer.

Comment: @samsher The above comment was now posted as an actual [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/216089/18612). To accept it, make sure you're first logged in, then click the checkmark icon to the left of it. It should then turn green if you did it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

either of the following would have happened

- grub, which allows multiple system to be configured perhaps dosen't contain windows boot details.
- or grub has the entry but it has selected ubuntu has default operating system and the selection time is kept at a low value, because of this reason its boot by default in Ubuntu.

in any case you will have to the following

- post the /etc/grub/menu.lst file
- download and install http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and paste the results of the same

Comment: i'm filling shame but how to get etc/grub/menu.lst file?

Comment: I don't think there is a `/etc/grub/menu.lst` file in 12.04 since 12.04 uses Grub2. And once again @gnuyoga please do post comments when requesting the OP for further information. Thanks :)